# Basic wave equation with Neumann boundary conditions on [-L, +L] domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I'm interested in solving the very basic wave equation with Neumann boundary conditions, except I have defined on some $ [-L, L]$ domain instead of the more common $[0,L]$ domain.

$$ u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx} = 0, \ \ \ \ \ u_x(\pm L) = 0 $$

if I simply take the usual solution kind for the spatial dependence (I have a simple cosinusoidal temporal dependence which can be easily treated, so I won't refer to it anymore):
$$ u = A \cos(kx) + B\sin(kx) $$
and I inject it in the boundary conditions, I find that
$$ A \sin(kL) = B \cos(kL) $$
$$-A \sin(kL) = B \cos(kL) $$
which gives me that $ B \cos(kL) = 0 $ but doesn't allow me to find the usual fact that $B = 0$  and simply have a condition for cos functions to exist.
I am unsure how to get out of this.
Is this normal and supposed to happen for the symmetric domain that I work with? Or is there something obvious that I'm not seeing?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: indeed, I find that $\beta = n \pi /L $ or that $\beta = (n+\frac{1}{2}) \pi/L$. Chosing either option leads to different solutions, respectively the typical cosine-only option and the other being the sinus-only option.
Which I'm confused about because of usual cos-only development for Neumann boundary conditions. I don't know what to make of this

Comment: I think I understood what you mean, so let me rephrase it to confirm that I got it: 
in the domain $[-L,+L]$, If I chose the condition $\beta_1=n\pi/L$, I'm left with the usual condition that $B=0$ so I get only the cosines. 
However, if I chose the condition $\beta_2 = (n+\frac{1}{2}) \pi/L$ instead, I get to the condition that $A\sin(\beta L) =0$ implies that $A=0$ instead, so I'm left with only the sines but with wavevector $\beta = \beta_2$. 

So I'm free to chose either condition, with no difference at all in the description? Is that correct, have I understood you well? Thanks

Comment: I naively thought there would be no difference in the description, however, upon plotting these functions for the two different condions (i.e. plotting $\sin(\beta_2 x)$ and $\cos(\beta_1 x)$), I do notice that they are nothing alike. So I guess it's not irrelevent which condition on $\beta$ I chose. 
Now what I wonder is: can I arbitrarily chose to consider that $\beta = \beta_1$? and discard entirely the $\beta = \beta_2$ option? so that I'm left with only the cosine solutions?

Comment: I thought I had it figured out thanks to your last reply, but I can see that I'm still confused about something.
I thought the general solution would therefore look like $u = A_n \cos(\frac{n\pi}{L} x) + B_n \sin( \frac{(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi}{L}x)$ but I realize that this makes no sense, as then $u_{xx} \neq -\beta ^2 u$  (because the temporal dependence is cosinusoidal, the wave equation reads $\Omega^2 u + C^2 u_{xx} = 0$, hence $u_{xx} = \beta^2 u$ with $\beta = \Omega/C $).
I am convinced by what you said but I am still unable to write coherently the general solution...?